# crystal reports asking for database password when i have not set any

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Crystal reports is asking for database user and password when i try to view a report but i have not set any for my local *.sdf file. 
My conection string only contains the dataset parameter and the passsword if i chose one but no user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
ReportDocument1.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(strLocationOfDatabase, "", "UserName", "Password")
```

or if you dont have username and password :

```
ReportDocument1.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(strLocationOfDatabase, "", False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when there is a mismatch between report parameters and the data provided to the report.

Answer (score 0):

don't refresh the report-

`CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()`

it worked for me I just deleted that line.